# Killing a thread does not work

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a simple call to a thread:

```
aThread = threading.Thread(target=singleDriverThread, args=(d[0]))
```

and then I start it (aThread.start)

when I need to stop the thread I do:

```
aThread.join()
```

but the thread keep running.. Help?

Comment: You simply cannot stop threads using `threading` API, you have to implement your own algorithms for this. `join` just waits for the thread to exit, blocking the current thread, so it doesn't send any kind of signal to `aThread`, telling it to terminate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: "join" is not "kill".  Calling `.join()` just means that the one thread will wait for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop a thread, you should either kill or signal the thread. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524459/stopping-a-thread-after-a-certain-amount-of-time) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446586/stop-a-thread-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) deal with stopping the thread. The `join` method only waits for the thread to exit.

In general, to make a thread stop gracefully, it is useful to have a communication channel with it so that a stop message / signal can be passed.

Answer (score 1):

The thread will continue to run until the callable `singleDriverThread` returns.

Example:

If your callable `singleDriverThread` looks like this the code will never stop:

```
def singleDriverThread():
    while True:
        # do stuff in eternal loop
        pass
```

But if `singleDriverThread` instead looks like this:

```
def singleDriverThread():
     # do stuff
     return
```

then the callable will return and the thread will join with the rest of your code.